# Custom Listview activity keep crashing

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

So I have this custom list adapter and listview thingy and I can't seem to get it to work. I've spent a couple of days now trying to figure how to fix it. Change this change that, nothing seems to work. Any idea? thanks

### MainActivity.class

---

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActvty";

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_actvity);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate, Started");

        ListView resList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.inListView);

        resClass wood = new resClass("Wood", 10);
        resClass iron = new resClass("Iron", 50);
        resClass meat = new resClass("Meat", 5);

        ArrayList<resClass> resArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        resArrayList.add(wood);
        resArrayList.add(iron);
        resArrayList.add(meat);
        ResListAdapter rsAdapter = new ResListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_actvity, resArrayList);
        resList.setAdapter(rsAdapter);
    }
}
```

### resClass.class

---

```
public class resClass {

    private String resType;
    private int resCount;

    public resClass(String resType, int resCount) {
        this.resType = resType;
        this.resCount = resCount;
    }

    public String getResType() {
        return resType;
    }

    public void setResType(String resType) {
        this.resType = resType;
    }

    public int getResCount() {
        return resCount;
    }

    public void setResCount(int resCount) {
        this.resCount = resCount;
    }
}
```

### ResListAdapter.class

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the adapter. But I'm not really sure.

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class ResListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<resClass>{

    private static final String TAG = "ResListAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public ResListAdapter( Context context, int resource, ArrayList<resClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        String resType = getItem(position).getResType();
        int resCount = getItem(position).getResCount();

        resClass res = new resClass(resType, resCount);

        LayoutInflater rsInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = rsInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView resTypeView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.res_name);
        TextView resCountView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.res_count);

        resTypeView.setText(resType);
        resCountView.setText(Integer.toString(resCount));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### The xml files

---

### MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="p_darkness.lonemandevelopmentstudio.com.p_darkness.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/inListView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Custom layout for the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/res_name"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="res_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/res_count"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="res_count"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's been really frustrating guys hope I can find the solution by asking this time.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no error when I installed it on my device. it just crash after launch

Comment: I have another activity before that one with the listview. that work fine until I switch to it

Comment: For me it worked perfectly fine. Can you check your logs. They will show the crash. If you say earlier it worked, then that means most probably you have not declared this activity in your manifest file. Can you check that?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Seriously? ._. how come it doesn't work on my device

Comment: Can you check your manifest if you have added activity there.

Comment: Ya I have both activity there.

Comment: So then only way i can help is after seeing the logs. 1 more thing that happened to me so you can check, I dont see any package statement in your activity class. hopefully it will be there but just check if not add it.  Usually if it crashes it comes in logs in Android monitor at the bottom. See if you have selected the right device there as well. there should be someting

Comment: 08-02 23:08:24.598 24919-24919/p_darkness.lonemandevelopmentstudio.com.p_darkness W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: I guess because of that?

Comment: So you use updateTintFilter anywhere in your layout. I think you have created some selector in drawable and using that selector somewhere right? but it is not in this activity so this activity should not be causing this.

Comment: Any other logs in your android monitor highlighted in big red color :)

Comment: I don't really know. I'm so confused right now. mind if we chat later? It's quite late here.

Comment: the whole logcat: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-rOY0viLBPyc0lUN1N3aU1FbGs

Comment: If something is crashing in your android app then it definitely means there is  some error. Check your app in emulator.

Comment: I can't run it on any emulator cause my laptop doesn't support that somehow (AMD apu) I can only run it on my real device. above is the logcat. I can't seem to figure what's the problem is

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't add the activity in the manifest correctly.